# IIS 10.0.14393.0 window server 2016, remove server header "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"

Tags: server, http-headers, iis-10, windows-server-2016

I have application running on window server 2016, IIS 10.0, when i am sending curl request to my domain

curl request :

```
curl -i X TRACE -d "test" https://example.com
```

I am getting following response headers :

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Tue, 09 Nov 2021 10:54:15 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 311
```

I want to remove information disclosed in Server response header "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0", I have tried following steps which claims to resolve issue but it is not working

- Open Regedit
- Navigate to: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
- If DisableServerHeader doesn't exist, create it (DWORD 32bit) and give it a value of 2. If it does exist, and the value isn't 2, set it to 2.
- Reboot the server OR restart the HTTP service by calling "net stop http" then "net start http"

I have already tried these steps on my server, but it is not working, also tried with URLrewrite, that too not working, how can i remove "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0" from server response header

Comment: Did you try to set `DisableServerHeader` to `1`? https://blog.lextudio.com/everything-you-might-need-about-iis-server-header-58ca268547be

Comment: @LexLi that too not working

Comment: That issue cannot be reproduced at least on my machines. You will have to open a support case with Microsoft via https://support.microsoft.com so that they can analyze what's special about your machine.